# Plotting labels on bar plots with position = "fill" in R ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

How does one plot "filled" bars with counts labels using ggplot2?

I'm able to do this for "stacked" bars. But I'm very confused otherwise.

Here is a reproducible example using *dplyr* and the *mpg* dataset

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

mpg_summ <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class, drv) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(total = sum(freq), 
         prop = freq/total)

g <- ggplot(mpg_summ, aes(x = class, y = prop, group = drv))
g + geom_col(aes(fill = drv)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = freq), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

But if I try to plot counts for filled bars it does not work

```
g <- ggplot(mpg_summ, aes(x=class, fill=drv))
g + stat_count(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), geom="bar", position="fill")  +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]

Further, if I try:

```
g <- ggplot(mpg_summ, aes(x=class, fill=drv))
g + geom_bar(aes(y = freq), position="fill")  +
  geom_text(aes(label = freq), position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

I get:

```
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I missed the fill portion from the last question. This should get you there:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mpg_summ <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class, drv) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(total = sum(freq), 
         prop = freq/total)

g <- ggplot(mpg_summ, aes(x = class, y = prop, group = drv))
g + geom_col(aes(fill = drv), position = 'fill') +
  geom_text(aes(label = freq), position = position_fill(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: how would you dodge the labels? as in where would I put the statement position=position_dodge(width=0.9)?

Comment: I believe only one position argument is allowed, so either `position_dodge` or `position_fill`